# Best way for nest child objects from objects array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nest

Hi masters i need to find the best way to convert this:

```
 [
  { "id": 1, "animal": "cat", "age": 6, "name": "loky" },
  { "id": 2, "animal": "cat", "age": 3, "name": "michu", "parent": 1 },
  { "id": 3, "animal": "cat", "age": 2, "name": "boots", "parent": 1 },
  { "id": 4, "animal": "dog", "age": 9, "name": "bones" },
  { "id": 5, "animal": "dog", "age": 6, "name": "chok", "parent": 4 },
  { "id": 6, "animal": "dog", "age": 6, "name": "cofee","parent": 4 }
]
```

to this:

```
 [
  { "id": 1,
    "animal": "cat",
    "age": 6,
    "name": "loky",
    "childs":[ { "id": 2, "animal": "cat", "age": 3, "name": "michu", "parent": 1 },
               { "id": 3, "animal": "cat", "age": 2, "name": "boots", "parent": 1 }] 
  }
  ,
  { "id": 4,
    "animal": "dog",
    "age": 9,
    "name": "bones",
    "childs":[{ "id": 5, "animal": "dog", "age": 6, "name": "chok", "parent": 4 },
              { "id": 6, "animal": "dog", "age": 6, "name": "cofee", "parent": 4 }]
  }
 ]
```

note that the "parent" key must be used to nest "childs" ,i create my way but with several functions is horrible ,i think there may be a more efficient way.

Thanks in advance sorry for my english

Comment: Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212), how to [access properties](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods). Without knowing what _“horrible”_ approach you took, how can we know which approaches constitute an adequate answer to this question?

Comment: Does [Convert array of objects with parent ids to a nested tree structure](/q/59779629/4642212) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const rows = [
  { id: 1, animal: 'cat', age: 6, name: 'loky' },
  { id: 2, animal: 'cat', age: 3, name: 'michu', parent: 1 },
  { id: 3, animal: 'cat', age: 2, name: 'boots', parent: 1 },
  { id: 4, animal: 'dog', age: 9, name: 'bones' },
  { id: 5, animal: 'dog', age: 6, name: 'chok', parent: 4 },
  { id: 6, animal: 'dog', age: 6, name: 'cofee', parent: 4 },
];

function map(rows) {
  const categories = Array.from(new Set(rows.map((row) => row.animal)));
  return categories.map((c) => {
    const parent = rows.find((row) => row.animal === c);
    parent.childs = rows
      .filter((r) => r.id !== parent.id && r.animal === c)
      .map((r) => ({ ...r, parent: parent.id }));
    return parent;
  });
}

console.log(map(row));
```

Simply create a mapper function to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helpme so much ,with your tips a mede other function working fine, but maybe can make some better?    `<br>`                                                                                                  ```function nester(arr){
  parents = rows.filter((row) => row.parent? '' : row.child=[])
  parents.forEach(function(e){
  arr.forEach((r)=> r.parent == e.id? e.child.push(r) :  '') })
  parents = parents.filter(elem => elem.child.length < 1? delete elem.child : elem)
  return parents 
  } ```

Comment: @CristianGarate Sorry I didn't get what you expected for this code. Explain more please

Comment: i do a pen  [link](https://codepen.io/cgaratea/pen/bGKoaKy)

Comment: @CristianGarate, we can optimize, which would make the code uglier. But on the other hand, we can gain the time complexity. You know there are always pros and cons that exist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```js
const rows = [
  { id: 1, animal: 'cat', age: 6, name: 'loky' },
  { id: 2, animal: 'cat', age: 3, name: 'michu', parent: 1 },
  { id: 3, animal: 'cat', age: 2, name: 'boots', parent: 1 },
  { id: 4, animal: 'dog', age: 9, name: 'bones' },
  { id: 5, animal: 'dog', age: 6, name: 'chok', parent: 4 },
  { id: 6, animal: 'dog', age: 6, name: 'cofee', parent: 4 },
];

function nester(arr) {
  const parents = rows.filter((r) => !r.parent);
  const children = rows.filter((r) => r.parent);
  return parents.map((p) => {
    return {
      ...p,
      children: children.filter((c) => c.parent === p.id),
    };
  });
}
console.log(nester(rows));
```

Comment: Thanks but supose i put another object like : { "id": 0, "animal": "cat", "age": 10, "name": "oldy" }   then with your function add a "children" empty property